# error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_COROUTINE_ABI': value '2' doesn't match value '1' in Qt6Cored.lib(qlocale_win.cpp.obj)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, conan, qt6

Environments:

- VC++2019 16.9.3 with /std:c++latest
- Conan version 1.40.3
- qt/6.2.2

Code:

`#include <coroutine>`

Error:

Qt6Cored.lib(qlocale_win.cpp.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_COROUTINE_ABI': value '1' doesn't match value '2' in xxx.obj

It seems that qt conflicts with STL coroutine.

Comment: I found the error message is from https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/coroutine. After I defined `_ALLOW_COROUTINE_ABI_MISMATCH` preprocessor variable, it could compile now.

Comment: The error is telling you that some of the code is using the pre-standardization ABI but you are using the standardized ABI. and the two ABIs are incompatible. If one kind of coroutine is passed to a function that expects the other kind, you risk a crash. (Generally speaking, /c++latest should not be used in production since it is a moving target. "[Features that have not been approved are subject to breaking changes or removal without notice and are provided on an as-is basis.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=msvc-170).")

Comment: @RaymondChen Which one contains pre-standardization ABI? Qt? Actually I don’t use coroutine, but I use asio and qt6, do you know if there is a way to disable coroutine for them?

Comment: The error message says `Qt6Cored.lib(qlocale_win.cpp.obj): value '1' doesn't match value '2' in xxx.obj`. So Qt6Cored.lib is using coroutine style 1, and xxx.obj is using style 2. I'll let you figure out which one is old and which is new, and which is qt6. If you're not using coroutines, why do you have `#include <coroutine>`?

Comment: @RaymondChen I use boost.asio, it seems that boost.asio uses coroutine.